# wine version portability with games

Tags: wine, versions

My wine version is 1.3.13 is it good to play high end games eg Suplereme commander,Crysis 2 in this version which I have.My microsoft office 2010 is working smoothly in this wine version.I have installed winetricks too.

Is their any latest version of microsoft office availabe of corse free for download.

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

The latest Wine version can be checked on [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/). The latest Wine version proposed by Canonical can be checked on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com).

As of today, 1st february 2014, the latest version of Wine is 1.7.11, and 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Your version of Wine is not "bad", but you could want to upgrade it. Normally, newer versions support the same applications than an old one, but with more accuracy, and new applications. You can install a newer version of Wine (1.6 or 1.5 is the stable version, following your Ubuntu's version) with these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

---

For the support of applications, a detailed website is available at : http://appdb.winehq.org/ which will help you see what applications works, with which Wine version.

> Example for Supreme Commander :
>
> On http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7038,
>   you'll see that Supreme Commander is "Gold" rated on Ubuntu 12.04,
>   with Wine 1.4, meaning it works well. 
>   You'll also see that you have to `winetricks vcrun2005` in order to play the game.
>
> You will notice the "HOWTO" section, at the bottom of the page, that can help you > if you have issues.
>
> From there, you can assume it will work on 13.10 and Wine 1.6, but you'll still have 
>   to `winetricks vcrun2005`.

---

For your last question, Microsoft doesn't offer any "free" Office programs. But you can try [LibreOffice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice), a free & open-source alternative for Linux/Mac/Windows.

Comment: Actually when I downloaded winetricks for my wine.I didnt checked wine version.

Comment: When you install the metapackage `wine`, the corresponding winetricks is automatically installed.

Comment: I am installing Supreme commander through CD.While istalling through '$wine autorun.exe' The installation window pops up.When I click install game button it says access denied in new message window. How shoul i resolve this problem.

Comment: I have no idea, this is a Ubuntu forum, your question is related to Wine. See their website for a forum and IRC.

Comment: If I helped you, you can upvote my answer or choose it as the answer you were looking for. Read http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer